# change the rails routing standard

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, response.redirect

after we create an new entry the standard redirect is everytime to the `:id`. how can i change it to an own_key.
We have designed our routes

```
resources :lists
match '/:own_key' => 'lists/show'
```

If we create an new entry the redirect go to /list/:id

Is there a way to change it to redirect to own_key?

```
def create
  @list = List.new(params[:list])
  @list = List.create!(params[:list])
  respond_with(@list)
end
```

Comment: If you want to redirect then what stops you from using `redirect_to` instead of `respond_with`?

Comment: We use respond_with because it allows to give more formats back like json and xml or atom. So now is the question back. The routes.rb contains `resources :lists`and this is always `:id` have we to overwrite all routes manual or is there an configoption ?

Comment: `:id` is hardcoded. But you can provide your `respond_with` with a block where you override html response: `{|format| format.html { redirect_to '/path'} }`. Other formats will be untouched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each model has a method called `to_param` which you can override

list.rb

```
class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  def to_param
    "#{own_key}.parameterize"
  end
end
```

This will make that the path changes from `/:id`, to `/:own_key`.

NOTE: This will change only the value of the parameter but not the name of the parameter.

Example: If you want to acces with an `own_key` value of `foo` the show action `/lists/foo` there will not be a `params[:own_key]`. You can access the `own_key` value by with `params[:id]` but not with `params[:own_key]`

```
Parameters: {"id"=>"foo"}
```